# Searching through IMAP folder for multiple criterion (python)

Tags: python, imap

Is it possible to use more than on criteria in one search request through imaplib?
i.e   emails sent after a date by a specific sender?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime
date = (datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(1)).strftime("%d-%b-%Y")
result, data = mail.uid('search', None, '(SENTSINCE {date})'.format(date=date))
```